# Proguard can't process this simple code

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I’ve found the problem in my codebase and I’ve tried to simplify it to the following snippet:

```
class DemoProguardIssue {
    fun main() {
        with(Unit) {
            runLambda {
                runLambda {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun runLambda(lambda: () -> Unit) = lambda()
}
```

Proguard complains with this error and breaks my build

```
Warning: com.example.DemoProguardIssue$main$1$1$1: can't find referenced class com.example.DemoProguardIssue$main$1$1
```

Rewriting the code to avoid the with was an easy workaround for me, but I’m scared there’s a bug in the compiler, or the desugar tool or something.

Can you help me figure out the problem?

Comment: I might be wrong, but maybe main shouldn't be obfuscated and having something like -keep class com.example.DemoProguardIssue in your progaurd-rules file might be worth it here. 

You can also do -keepclassmembers class * { fun main() }

Comment: Yes, it's compiler bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23172 . You can avoid this problem with proguard rules mentioned above.

Comment: Can I write a rule that covers this situation everywhere? I have a lot of classes with this problem, so writing proguard rules for each of them is not practical. I can disable proguard warnings but they are usually nice